# PHP get if variable is a pattern/regex

Tags: php, regex

Is there a way to detect if a variable is a pattern in PHP? I know this is possible in JavaScript since patterns are a variable type however in PHP, patterns are inside of strings.

```
if (is_pattern($myPattern)) {
        //...
}
```

Comment: You need to use preg_match() for that. If I understood correctly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP there is a function called **[preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match.php)** that basically does what you stated, it tests a string in search of a pattern/regex.

```
if (preg_match("/php/i", "php is the best programming language.")) {
    echo "A match has been found!";
} else {
    echo "No match found.";
}
```

In that case, preg_match would search for the string "php" inside the test string that you have passed as an argument.

Comment: You should (re)read the question! They want to know if a string is a pattern.